# How does concat works using ipython?

Tags: ipython

Can somebody explain me the code below?
Asume n_a and n_x are known.
Questions I have for the below code are:
for the second concat, why is there no , between : and n_a
and idem for the third contact (no , between n_a and :)?
What is the difference between : n_a and n_a : ?
What is the difference in : before and after the , (in both concats ?)

```
concat = np.zeros((n_a + n_x, m))
concat[: n_a, :] = a_prev
concat[n_a :, :] = xt
```

Comment: `:n` and `n:` are both Python slices.  The general slice pattern is `start:stop:step`.  You should be familiar with this from working with Python lists.  `numpy` generalizes this by allowing slices for several dimensions, separated by the comma.  Usually we write `x[n:, :]` but the extra space in 'n :' doesn't matter.

Comment: @hpaulj can you clarify with an example. Eg: with the code I write in my question?

Comment: @hpaulj can you give fictive value to concat and then tell me what the value will be for a_prev and xt ? It should really help me further.

Comment: Have you experimented with lists and arrays?  What do those different slicing expressions produce?  You've tagged this with `ipython`, which means you can and should be doing these calculations interactively.  You can see for yourself what `concat[:3,:]` produces.  An for that testing, start with something like `np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)` so you can see right off which rows you select.